# Haskell return type confusion

Tags: haskell

In working through "Haskell Programming from first principles" I am puzzled by the answer to the following question:

> If the type of `kessel` is `(Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a`, then the type of
>   `kessel 1 2` is
>
> a) `Integer`
>   b) `Int`
>   c) `a`
>   d) `(Num a, Ord a) => a`
>   e) `Ord a => a`
>   f) `Num a => a`

The answer is d) - but I think the answer should be e), since the only requirement in the type signature for the first argument (a) is that it be an `Ord`. So why not the return?

```
kessel 'd' 2
```

is valid and it is of type `Char` - nothing about `Num`!

What don't I understand?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We demand `Num a` so that `1 :: a` makes sense.

Comment: As a side note, this question really sucks: the "correct" answer depends dearly on some of the less interesting vagaries of the Haskell type system, notably defaulting and number literal polymorphism and depending on how you interpret the question also the monomorphism restriction. If you had used a different class than `Num` for the `Num b` constraint (and an appropriate alternate argument to `2`, of course), likely the correct answer would have been "it's an ambiguous type error", and if you write `foo = kessel 1 2` in a file and ask ghci about its type it will tell you `foo :: Integer`!

Comment: ...and to be clear, by "this question" I don't mean the question you're asking sucks. I think you did a great job of setting up your question. I'm saying the question from "Haskell Programming from first principals" is confusing and (in my opinion) badly-framed question.

Comment: @DanielWagner I can't figure out how to produce any of the problematic results you're describing. If I type `:t (undefined :: (Ord a, Monoid b) => a -> b -> a) 1 "x"` into ghci, I get `(Num a, Ord a) => a`. What am I missing?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Try `:t (undefined :: (Ord a, Monoid b) => a -> b -> a) 1 mempty`. The parallel here is that `2` is polymorphic over all `Num` instances, and `mempty` is polymorphic over all `Monoid` instances. Using `"x"` instead of `mempty` selects a particular `Monoid` and avoids the ambiguity problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `1` is `Num a => a`. When you pass it as the first argument to `kessel`, its type is restricted to `(Num a, Ord a) => a` because `kessel` requires `Ord` for its first argument. And since the type of the result is the same as that of the first argument, you get `(Num a, Ord a) => a` as the result type.

Note that this has nothing to do with the type of the second argument. I imagine the second argument is just there to confuse you. If the function were:

```
kessel :: Ord a => a -> a
```

then the type of `kessel 1` would still be `(Num a, Ord a) => a`. The `Num` is there because that's the type of `1`, not because of the type of `kessel`.

The type of `kessel 'd' 2` is `Char`, as opposed to `Ord Char => Char`, because `Char` is already a concrete type that implements `Ord`, so the restriction is not necessary.

Comment: "...then the type of kessel 1 would still be (Num a, Ord a) => a. The Num is there because that's the type of 1, not because of the type of kessel." Ahh... that lifted the veil. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

> `kessel 'd' 2`
>
> is valid and it is of type `Char` - nothing about `Num`!

Yes! `kessel 1 2` and `kessel 'd' 2` have different types,

```
λ> kessel = undefined :: (Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a
kessel :: (Num b, Ord a) => a -> b -> a

λ> :t kessel 1 2
kessel 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a

λ> :t kessel 'd' 2
kessel 'd' 2 :: Char
```

which is possible because `kessel` is *polymorphic*.